# Attribute table deletes and swaps values when saving layer edits - QGIS 3.20

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table

I am currently doing landcover mapping within the catchments of river systems in order to assess the overall integrity and functionality of these systems, so I have to classify and calculate the area of different landcover classes within their catchments. The area is approximately 12000ha and I have to get quite detailed so it is a rather painstaking process.

I am manually digitizing the landcover classes using the 'Split feature' and 'Fill ring' tools in the advanced digitizing toolbar, and manually labelling each landcover class. I am using an ESRI shapefile format. I have created a text attribute into which I enter the different landcover classes. My approach is to map out all of the different landcover classes and then classify them thereafter. I generally try to save layer edits every 5 minutes or so - and I always save my shape edits before starting on my text edits in the attribute table. In this particular case, I have mapped out all of the different landcover classes and am busy labeling them.

However, each time I save the layer edits, a number of the classes that I have entered completely disappeared while other classes magically swap classifications and a number of the polygons disappear completely as well.

For example, I had classified a piece of land as 'Commercial crops', but after I had clicked save, it was reclassified to 'Dam'. I have had the experience in the past where the attribute table empties itself of most values when clicking save, but never have I experienced this swapping of values.

I have recently upgraded from QGIS 3.16 to the newest 3.20.

Could that have something to do with it?

I am not using a spatial index on the layer. There are no other projects in which this particular shapefile is open or active and it is only active in my project once.

Comment: You might indicate what kind of layer you are editing, be it shapefile, file geodatabase, geopackage, etc.   A few other questions I can think of off the top of my head.  Do you save your shape edits prior to making your table edits? Do you have a spatial index on the layer?  Does the layer you are editing have a definition query on it, or is it in your project more than once, or in another project which might be open?  Have you checked the geometry validity?

Comment: Where is your shapefile stored (on the computer running QGIS, a network drive, cloud storage, ....) ? Did you already try to close everything and restart your computer ? Could you try another data format like geopackage ?